# Javascript mouseover image failure

Tags: javascript, html

This is what I have so far, I have been watching a ton of Javascript videos and I feel I mimicked them solid but this is still not functioning as I want.

Than being, it changes from logo1 to logo2 on mousover. This is homework. However homework that is important to me so any help or guidance would be appreciated.

```
</head>

<body>
<p>
<div>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Pre load images for rollover
function imgOver(id) 
{
    document.getElementById(id).src="logo1.jpg";
}

function imgOut(id) 
{
    document.getElementById(id).src="logo2.jpg";
}

</script>   
<a href="#" onmouseover="imgOver('logo1');" onmouseout="imgOut('logo2')">
<img alt="logo" height="150" src="images/Logo1.jpeg" width="110" />
</a>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

New Code, its still....not working! =(

```
</head>

<body>
<div>
<p>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Pre load images for rollover
function imgOver() 
{
    document.getElementById('logo').src="images/logo1.jpg"; // ensure correct image path
}

function imgOut() 
{
    document.getElementById('logo').src="images/logo2.jpg"; // ensure correct image path
}
</script>   
<a href="#" onmouseover="imgOver('logo1');" onmouseout="imgOut('logo2')">
<img alt="logo" height="150" src="images/Logo1.jpeg" width="110" />
</a>
</p>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Also, I know that there are many examples on stackoverflow but they are doing it a different way I have not been taught and do not quite understand yet.

Comment: is it not changing back on mouseout?

Comment: Its not...I am testing it in chrome and firefox but it just sits there static...

Comment: techfoobar's answer should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not pass the image element's `ID` to your `imgOver` and `imgOut` functions since the `ID` never changes, your functions should be changed to:

```
function imgOver() {
    document.getElementById('logo').src="logo1.jpg"; // ensure correct image path
}

function imgOut() {
    document.getElementById('logo').src="logo2.jpg"; // ensure correct image path
}
```

Secondly, ensure you specify the correct path to `logo1.jpg` and `logo2.jpg`. For example: form your original HTML it looks like you'll need to use **images/logo1.jpg** and **images/logo2.jpg** respectively.

---

Your image element needs to have an ID. `<img id="logo" alt="logo" height="150" src="images/Logo1.jpeg" width="110" />`

**Full Source:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function imgOver() {
    document.getElementById('logo').src="images/logo1.jpg"; // ensure correct image path
}
function imgOut() {
    document.getElementById('logo').src="images/logo2.jpg"; // ensure correct image path
}
</script>   
<a href="#" onmouseover="imgOver()" onmouseout="imgOut()">
    <!-- note the id="logo" part below -->
    <img id="logo" alt="logo" height="150" src="images/Logo1.jpeg" width="110" />
</a>
```

Comment: Check out my updated answer. your image element needs to have an ID (= logo)

Comment: Have posted the full source, that should get you started.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Pre load images for rollover
function imgSwap(imgSrc) 
{
    document.getElementById('logo').src = "images/"+imgSrc+".jpeg";
}

</script>   
<a href="#" onmouseover="imgSwap('Logo1');" onmouseout="imgSwap('Logo2')">
<img id="logo" alt="logo" height="150" src="images/Logo1.jpeg" width="110" />
</a>
```

Previously, you we're passing in an `id` which was not used. Also, the src needs to point to the `images/` directory.